# Is it possible to customize bootstrap template with Python?

Tags: python, web, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap template that has some divs. Classes of these divs I know.
For example, there is a div with class "summary".
I want to be able to push some text in this div using that class.
lets assume I write something like this.

```
<div class="summary">
<p>
</p>
</div>
```

The above is my HTML from the template.

```
template = read_html_template("path of template here")
template_divs = template.divs()
template_divs['summary']['p'].push("This is summary text.")
```

Is it possible via any package, library in Python? Please note I know about flask. I want to be able to do it in simple python.

Comment: You can probably work something out using BeautifulSoup. It is often used for scraping but can also alter HTML data if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [jinja2](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/) for this. A basic example:

```
from jinja2 import Template
t = Template('<div class="summary"><p>{{summary_text}}</p></div>')
rendered_template = t.render(summary_text="This is summary text.")
print(rendered_template)
```

Output:

```
<div class="summary"><p>This is summary text.</p></div>
```

You can also use html file templates, etc. Plenty of resources available online to get you started.